# How to combine number/string value to enter value in Calendar

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let today = new Date();
let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
let selectYear = document.getElementById("year");
let selectMonth = document.getElementById("month");

let btn=document.getElementById("button");
let btnTag=document.getElementById("buttonTag");
//btn.addEventListener("click",getText);

let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"];

let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);



function next() {
    currentYear = (currentMonth === 11) ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
    currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}

function previous() {
    currentYear = (currentMonth === 0) ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
    currentMonth = (currentMonth === 0) ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}

function jump() {
    currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
    currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
}



function showCalendar(month, year) {

    let firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
    let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();

    let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body"); // body of the calendar

    // clearing all previous cells
    tbl.innerHTML = "";

    // filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
    monthAndYear.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + year;
    selectYear.value = year;
    selectMonth.value = month;

    // creating all cells
    let date = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        //creating individual cells, filing them up with data.
        for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
                

                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode("");
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);


            }
            else if (date > daysInMonth) {
                break;
            }

            else {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
                if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
                    cell.classList.add("bg-success");
                } // color today's date
                if(date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()){
                    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        cell.innerHTML=   today.getDate() + "="  +document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
                      });
                

                }

                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                date++;
            }


        }

        tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kalender</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container col-sm-4 col-md-7 col-lg-4 mt-5">
    <div class="card">
        <h3 class="card-header" id="monthAndYear"></h3>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>So</th>
                <th>Mo</th>
                <th>Di</th>
                <th>Mi</th>
                <th>Do</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sa</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="calendar-body">

            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-inline">

            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="previous" onclick="previous()">Zurück</button>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="next" onclick="next()">Nächster</button>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <form class="form-inline">
            <label class="lead mr-2 ml-2" for="month">Wechsel zu: </label>
            <select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="month" id="month" onchange="jump()">
                <option value=0>Jan</option>
                <option value=1>Feb</option>
                <option value=2>Mär</option>
                <option value=3>Apr</option>
                <option value=4>Mai</option>
                <option value=5>Jun</option>
                <option value=6>Jul</option>
                <option value=7>Aug</option>
                <option value=8>Sep</option>
                <option value=9>Okt</option>
                <option value=10>Nov</option>
                <option value=11>Dez</option>
            </select>


            <label for="year"></label><select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="year" id="year" onchange="jump()">
            <option value=1990>1990</option>
            <option value=1991>1991</option>
            <option value=1992>1992</option>
            <option value=1993>1993</option>
            <option value=1994>1994</option>
            <option value=1995>1995</option>
            <option value=1996>1996</option>
            <option value=1997>1997</option>
            <option value=1998>1998</option>
            <option value=1999>1999</option>
            <option value=2000>2000</option>
            <option value=2001>2001</option>
            <option value=2002>2002</option>
            <option value=2003>2003</option>
            <option value=2004>2004</option>
            <option value=2005>2005</option>
            <option value=2006>2006</option>
            <option value=2007>2007</option>
            <option value=2008>2008</option>
            <option value=2009>2009</option>
            <option value=2010>2010</option>
            <option value=2011>2011</option>
            <option value=2012>2012</option>
            <option value=2013>2013</option>
            <option value=2014>2014</option>
            <option value=2015>2015</option>
            <option value=2016>2016</option>
            <option value=2017>2017</option>
            <option value=2018>2018</option>
            <option value=2019>2019</option>
            <option value=2020>2020</option>
            <option value=2021>2021</option>
            <option value=2022>2022</option>
            <option value=2023>2023</option>
            <option value=2024>2024</option>
            <option value=2025>2025</option>
            <option value=2026>2026</option>
            <option value=2027>2027</option>
            <option value=2028>2028</option>
            <option value=2029>2029</option>
            <option value=2030>2030</option>
        </select></form>
  
        <textarea placeholder="Gebe dein Termin ein" id="myTextArea" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
        <button id="button">Klick</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!--<button name="jump" onclick="jump()">Go</button>-->
<script src="scripts.js"></script>

<!-- Optional JavaScript for bootstrap -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I want to enter information(in string) in a specific date in calendar. so far i can enter information in the current day but i dont know how to do it for the day i choose in my html file. How can i combine the text and day value in html so i need to click just once to activate a buttonlistener.
Below is the relevant code:

```
    <textarea placeholder="Gebe dein Termin ein" id="myTextArea" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
    <button id="button">Klick</button>
    <input type="number" name="Tag" id="tag">
    <button id="buttonTag">Klick</button>
```

```
    let firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
    let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();

    let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body"); // body of the calendar

    // clearing all previous cells
    tbl.innerHTML = "";

    // filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
    monthAndYear.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + year;
    selectYear.value = year;
    selectMonth.value = month;

    // creating all cells
    let date = 1;
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        // creates a table row
        let row = document.createElement("tr");

        //creating individual cells, filing them up with data.
        for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {


                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode("");
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);


            }
            else if (date > daysInMonth) {
                break;
            }

            else {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
                if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
                    cell.classList.add("bg-success");
                } // color today's date
                if(date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()){
                    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        cell.innerHTML=   today.getDate() + "="  +document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
                      });


                }

                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);
                date++;
            }


        }

        tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.
    }
```

Comment: Can you add your current working functionality to code snippet.

Comment: and some more clear info about what you are expecting , then i can help you.

Comment: hey @saravana thank you for your reply
i have added the code snippet and i want you to be able to select a specific day to add an entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added some basic example , explore it yourself. if not working in the run snippet save the code to your local and try testing.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Kalender</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container col-sm-4 col-md-7 col-lg-4 mt-5">
        <div class="card">
            <h3 class="card-header" id="monthAndYear"></h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-sm" id="calendar">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>So</th>
                    <th>Mo</th>
                    <th>Di</th>
                    <th>Mi</th>
                    <th>Do</th>
                    <th>Fri</th>
                    <th>Sa</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="calendar-body">

                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="form-inline">

                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="previous" onclick="previous()">Zurück</button>

                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary col-sm-6" id="next" onclick="next()">Nächster</button>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <form class="form-inline">
                <label class="lead mr-2 ml-2" for="month">Wechsel zu: </label>
                <select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="month" id="month" onchange="jump()">
                    <option value=0>Jan</option>
                    <option value=1>Feb</option>
                    <option value=2>Mär</option>
                    <option value=3>Apr</option>
                    <option value=4>Mai</option>
                    <option value=5>Jun</option>
                    <option value=6>Jul</option>
                    <option value=7>Aug</option>
                    <option value=8>Sep</option>
                    <option value=9>Okt</option>
                    <option value=10>Nov</option>
                    <option value=11>Dez</option>
                </select>


                <label for="year"></label><select class="form-control col-sm-4" name="year" id="year" onchange="jump()">
                <option value=1990>1990</option>
                <option value=1991>1991</option>
                <option value=1992>1992</option>
                <option value=1993>1993</option>
                <option value=1994>1994</option>
                <option value=1995>1995</option>
                <option value=1996>1996</option>
                <option value=1997>1997</option>
                <option value=1998>1998</option>
                <option value=1999>1999</option>
                <option value=2000>2000</option>
                <option value=2001>2001</option>
                <option value=2002>2002</option>
                <option value=2003>2003</option>
                <option value=2004>2004</option>
                <option value=2005>2005</option>
                <option value=2006>2006</option>
                <option value=2007>2007</option>
                <option value=2008>2008</option>
                <option value=2009>2009</option>
                <option value=2010>2010</option>
                <option value=2011>2011</option>
                <option value=2012>2012</option>
                <option value=2013>2013</option>
                <option value=2014>2014</option>
                <option value=2015>2015</option>
                <option value=2016>2016</option>
                <option value=2017>2017</option>
                <option value=2018>2018</option>
                <option value=2019>2019</option>
                <option value=2020>2020</option>
                <option value=2021>2021</option>
                <option value=2022>2022</option>
                <option value=2023>2023</option>
                <option value=2024>2024</option>
                <option value=2025>2025</option>
                <option value=2026>2026</option>
                <option value=2027>2027</option>
                <option value=2028>2028</option>
                <option value=2029>2029</option>
                <option value=2030>2030</option>
            </select></form>
      
            <textarea placeholder="Gebe dein Termin ein" id="myTextArea" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
            <button id="button">Klick</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--<button name="jump" onclick="jump()">Go</button>-->


    <!-- Optional JavaScript for bootstrap -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

```
<script>





    let today = new Date();
    let currentMonth = today.getMonth();
    let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
    let selectYear = document.getElementById("year");
    let selectMonth = document.getElementById("month");
    var selectedCell  =' d';
    
    let btn=document.getElementById("button");
    let btnTag=document.getElementById("buttonTag");

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
document.querySelectorAll('#calendar-body td').forEach(e1 => {
        if(e1.className === 'bg-success'){
            e1.innerHTML += document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;

        }
    });
    });
    //btn.addEventListener("click",getText);

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"];

    let monthAndYear = document.getElementById("monthAndYear");
    showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);



    function next() {
        currentYear = (currentMonth === 11) ? currentYear + 1 : currentYear;
        currentMonth = (currentMonth + 1) % 12;
        showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    }

    function previous() {
        currentYear = (currentMonth === 0) ? currentYear - 1 : currentYear;
        currentMonth = (currentMonth === 0) ? 11 : currentMonth - 1;
        showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    }

    function jump() {
        currentYear = parseInt(selectYear.value);
        currentMonth = parseInt(selectMonth.value);
        showCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    }

  

    function showCalendar(month, year) {

        let firstDay = (new Date(year, month)).getDay();
        let daysInMonth = 32 - new Date(year, month, 32).getDate();

        let tbl = document.getElementById("calendar-body"); // body of the calendar

        // clearing all previous cells
        tbl.innerHTML = "";
        // filing data about month and in the page via DOM.
        monthAndYear.innerHTML = months[month] + " " + year;
        selectYear.value = year;
        selectMonth.value = month;

        // creating all cells
        let date = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            // creates a table row
            let row = document.createElement("tr");

            //creating individual cells, filing them up with data.
            for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (i === 0 && j < firstDay) {
                    

                    let cell = document.createElement("td");
                    let cellText = document.createTextNode("");
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    
                    row.appendChild(cell);


                }
                else if (date > daysInMonth) {
                    break;
                }

                else {
                    let cell = document.createElement("td");
                    let cellText = document.createTextNode(date);
                    if (date === today.getDate() && year === today.getFullYear() && month === today.getMonth()) {
                        cell.classList.add("bg-success");
                    } // color today's date
                    

                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                    date++;
                }


            }

            tbl.appendChild(row); // appending each row into calendar body.
        }
        document.querySelectorAll('#calendar-body td')
.forEach(e =>{ 
    e.addEventListener("click", adddevnt)});
    }
    function adddevnt(e) {
    // Here, `this` refers to the element the event was hooked on
    document.querySelectorAll('#calendar-body td').forEach(e1 => {
        e1.className='';
    });
   e.target.classList.add("bg-success");

}
</script>
```

Comment: youre a genius men. Thanks a lot.